# writing to a list which name comes from an argument passed through function call

Tags: python, string, list, append

I have a function that asks for the positions of a chess piece on a board.
The function is

```
findPiece(piece)
```

so I can call this function like this:

```
findPiece(whitePawn)
```

The function finds out where all the white pawns are and returns this. Now I want to write the positions to the global list

```
whitePawnPositions[]
```

If I write

```
whitePawnPositions.append(position)
```

it works fine. But sometimes I want to know where another piece is, so it's not the `whitePawnPositions` list but the `blackRookPositions` list. I wrote:

```
piecePositions = (str(piece) + "Positions)
```

This works, so if I type `print(piecePositions)` it returns the correct list.

But now I want to write to this list by doing this:

```
piecePositions.append(position)
```

But this doesn't work.

Any idea why? It should be easy I guess. It somehow looks not right anyway because it seems like I'm trying to write to the string `piecePosition`, instead of the list.

Comment: Use a dictionary to store the lists, so the "variable" becomes a string key.

Comment: You _could_ access the variables as strings using [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#globals), but it's not a good practice. Besides, "position of pieces" is a concept that encloses all those lists, so it would make sense to put all together in a dictionary of positions.

Comment: yes I'm reading into dictionaries now. Completely new to me, but it seems very useful once you understand them.

Comment: You won't get far writing Python code without understanding `dict`s. Spend your time learning to use them, not trying to figure out ways to do things without them.

Answer (score 0):

`whitePawnPositions[]` is a list. To add elements to lists there is the `.append()` function. How to deal with lists you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) again.

Back to your question. `piecePositions` is a string and not a list and does not have the `.append()` function. In python there are several possibilities to concatenate a string. More about that you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp). Because I don't know whether you want to work with a string or a list, I'll just show you both options.

Here are a few small examples of how to concatenate strings in python. Whith this you would work if it should be a list.

The easyest:

```
print('Hello' + 'World')
```

The same works for variables:

```
a = 'Hello'
b = 'World'
print(a + ' ' + b)
```

Another option is the f’string formatting which uses the same syntactic resemblance like jinja2:

```
variable = 'World'    
print(f"Hello {variable}")
```

This line makes piecePositions a sting

```
piecePositions = (str(piece) + "Positions")
```

if you cast the `piece` (which should be a list i guess) in a string and concatenate that whith another string that makes the whole thing a string. if you want to continue working with lists this is what you are looking for:

```
piece.append('Positions')
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks a lot! 
the thing is, I want the string to be the name of list. So I guess that's where it gets complicated. I know how to concatenate strings and how to append lists. It's just that I want the content of the string to be the list to write to.

Wow, it's so hard to explain...

Comment: Is it possible you would like to use a dictionary? That thing has keys and value pairs. you can use your string as key and the list as value and vice versa. You always could access the list by your string... I guess the 'key' is what you mean with 'name of the list'. Have a look if that is what you are looking for https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: yes I'm reading into dictionaries now. Completely new to me, but it seems very useful once you understand them.

Comment: F-strings have nothing (aside from a syntactic resemblance) to do with jinja2.

Comment: hope this let you sleep better tonight.